# Trouble finding SharePoint List URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've developed a web part that combines data from several lists and makes a report for the users. The webpart has several configurable attributes for the lists (like this)

```
[WebBrowsable(true),
   WebDisplayName("Hours List"),
   WebDescription("Work Hours List"),
   Category("Report Configuration"),
   DefaultValue("FY14 Work Hours"),
   Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
    public string HoursListName
    {
        get
        {
            return hoursListName;
        }
        set
        {
            hoursListName = value;
        }
    }

    private string hoursListName = "FY14 Work Hours";
```

Then I use this to get my list:

```
SPWeb ehsWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList hoursList = ehsWeb.Lists[hoursListName];
```

It works great on Dev where the URL is `Lists/FY14 Work Hours/FY14%20Work%20Hours.aspx`

However it doesn't work on the Production site where the url is:
`Lists/IRF/FY14%20Work%20Hours.aspx`

The IRF seems to be the part that is messing me up. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your list is actually called IRF, use that as the name. The .aspx page(and name) is just a view.

Comment: I tried that, but I got this message: List 'IRF' does not exist at site with URL 'http://oursite.com/corp/EHS/EHSKPIs'.

Comment: Did you rename the list at some point? You may want to try the new long name.

Comment: I didn't, but it's possible the Site Owner did at one point.
I'll do some experiments with a console app to see what I can determine. Thank you!

Comment: Update: I was able to find the real list names by using SharePoint Designer. Apparently they had been changed several times and did not correspond to what the url was showing at all.